# shorter way to collect and send data without a form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have some (15) `input, select, and textarea` tags on page - without a form
need to collect their values and insert them into a database
this code works fine, but I hope there is a way to short it
on client side - maybe some kind of `serialize`
on server side - especially on `execute` statement - maybe some kind of loop

```
$('#btn_send').on('click', function(){
    let obj = {};
    $('input, select, textarea').each(function(){
        let a = $(this).attr('name');
        obj[a] = $(this).val();
    });
    let str = JSON.stringify(obj);
    $.post('reg.php', {fn: 'btn_send', args: [str]}, function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

**reg.php**

```
function btn_send($str){
    global $db;
    $obj = json_decode($str);
    // here are table columns
    $a = "name,birth,gender,city,state,gmail,fb,tw,web,phone,occ,food,note,uname,pass";
    $b = ':a' . str_replace(',', ', :a', $a);
    $sq = "insert into members ($a) values ($b)";
    $st = $db->prepare($sq);
    $st->execute([
        ":aname" => $obj->name,
        ":agender" => $obj->gender,
        //... and so on - 15 items
    ]);
    echo 'success';
}
```

Comment: If the code works and you just want someone to review it and come with improvement suggestions, please post it over at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead. Stack overflow is for when you run into issue and need help getting your code working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code sample, it looks like the elements of your object have the same names as the columns in your table. In that case, you can simplify your code by converting the incoming JSON to an array rather than an object and utilising the fact that [`PDOStatement::execute`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) allows the array keys to not include the `:` in the names:

```
$obj = json_decode($str, true);
// here are table columns
$cols = array_keys($obj);
$a = implode(',', $cols);
$b = ':a' . str_replace(',', ', :a', $a);
$sq = "insert into members ($a) values ($b)";
$st = $db->prepare($sq);
$st->execute($obj);
```

Should the behaviour of `execute` change in the future, you can make an array with the keys preceded with `:` using [`array_combine`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) and [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
array_combine(array_map(function ($k) { return ":$k"; }, $cols), $obj)
```

You would then pass this array to `execute` in place of `$obj`.

Answer (score 1):

Something I made not sure if it even compiles, just was bored this is how I would do the 15 items or so part.

```
function btn_send($str){
    global $db;
    $obj = json_decode($str);
    // here are table columns
    $a = "name,birth,gender,city,state,gmail,fb,tw,web,phone,occ,food,note,uname,pass";
    $b = ':a' . str_replace(',', ', :a', $a);
    $sq = "insert into members ($a) values ($b)";
    $st = $db->prepare($sq);
    $sqlArray = array();
    foreach($obj as $key => $value) {
        $sqlArray[]= array(":a".$key => $value);
    }
    $st->execute($sqlArray);

    echo 'success';
}
```

Edit: I looked at Nick's answer it seems you don't even need to do all the hard stuff I did, you can just pass `$obj` wow they made it so easy now